# How to prevent default addClass function with onclick and return the function at a given date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to dynamically add a class to a link on a given day of the week to display it and have the link stay visible until clicked. When clicked, the class should be removed which will then hide the link and it stays hidden until the day of the week returns.

**This is what I have tried.**

```
jQuery(function($) {
var day = new Date().getDay();

if( day == 4 ) {
    $(".link").addClass("shown");
}
$(".link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).removeClass("shown");
});
});
```

It removes correctly when clicked but as long as the 24hr period exist, the link displays when the page reloads. What would be the correct coding to achieve the goal?

Comment: You'd either have to use cookies or some sort of storage on the server, otherwise the Javascript will run fresh on reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on louisik1's answer, and my comment, here's a basic example of how it could be done with cookies:

https://jsfiddle.net/L9ojth2n/1/ has the working version of this.

First, on the click, check which link it is, and store it as a cookie expiring at midnight the next day (in case you want to display links multiple days of the week):

```
var expires=new Date();
expires.setDate(expires.getDate()+1);
expires.setHours(0);
expires.setMinutes(0);
expires.setSeconds(0);
expires.setMilliseconds(0);
document.cookie="clickedLink"+$(".link").index(this)+"=yes;expires="+expires.toUTCString()+";path=/";
```

And second, when you next visualize the links, check for cookies to see if any of the links have already been clicked:

```
if(document.cookie.split(';').reduce(function(object,cookie){
    var data=cookie.split('=');
    object[data[0].trim()]=data[1];
    return object;
},{})['clickedLink'+$('.link').index(this)]!="yes"){
    $(this).addClass("shown");
}
```

Note that tech savvy users may be able to undermine this and display links multiple times in a day if they delete their cookies. It's most secure to require logins and store data on the server for specific users.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to store the record of the user already clicking the link. Since the page will reload all the script and re-set all variables etc., you need to store 'long life' data by some other means, of which there are several.

1. Typically in the past it was done with cookies to store that data on the users' computer.
2. Modern browsers support Local Storage, which has a very simple syntax to store data on the users' computer, like cookies.  But it does require HTML5.
3. Storing the information in your server code somehow (such as saving to SQL, or storing to some kind of document (txt, xml, csv) in your server (('user Mike clicked date link at this time/day')), and then sending that detail down to your javascript when you load the page.
4. Store it in the URL as a query or hash parameter.  This can be changed or erased by the user so it cannot be relied upon to be there (or not be there) when you expect it.

Any of those would be the correct method to achieve the goal, and each one is well documented everywhere.

Cheers